# Php Array Count no work me

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have in txt file this data for products of shop :

```
product 1
product 1
product 2
product 2
product 2
product 1
product 1
product 3
product 3
product 3
product 1
product 1
product 3
product 1
```

Ok , the people add products to the card of shopping and these products insert in general txt

**For recover the data i use the next script :**

```
<?php

$file_data=file("products.txt");


for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($file_data);$i++)
{


/// Create array of groups


$global_products[]=$file_data[$i];

}


/// Now i want get the products and the number in each case for example of the product 1 i have 6 for the product 2 i have 3 and for the product 3 i have 4 , ok for get this i can use thi function 




$prr=array_count_values($global_productos);

print_r (object2array($prr),true);



?>
```

If i use print_r i can get the products and number in each case but how i can get in other mode , for example for use with normal function of print or echo , i try get finally the data show as this :

```
Product 1 (6)
Product 2 (3)
Product 3 (4)
```

**Thank´s Regards**

Comment: Loop through the array `$prr` and print out each entry the way you like it.

Comment: i guess the op wants to count the number of ocurrences for each product in file

Comment: Can you tell me how i can do this , can you put example , thank´s !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the code below

```
<?php

$file_data=file("output_rrr.txt");


for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($file_data);$i++)
{


/// Create array of groups


$global_products[]=$file_data[$i];

}

/// Now i want get the products and the number in each case for example of the product 1 i have 6 for the product 2 i have 3 and for the product 3 i have 4 , ok for get this i can use thi function 




$prr=array_count_values($global_products);
foreach($prr as $key=>$value)
{
    echo trim($key).": ".$value."<br/>";

}




?>
```